# Play & Ebean - get first record

Tags: java, mysql, sql, playframework, ebean

How is it possible to get the first record of a table in my database using the play.db.ebean.Model.Finder, like a "first" method. The corresponding SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Can we also have this done on the latest ebean and play? After Finder moved out Play things are getting complicated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume model `Student`

```
@Entity
public class Student{

@Id
public int id;

public String name;
}
```

Model finder will be

```
public static Finder<Long,Student> find = new Finder(Long.class, Student.class);
```

Retrieve Student limit by 1

```
public static Student getStudent()
{
    // Use setMaxRows(limit_by)
    return find.setMaxRows(1).findUnique();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. new to ebean, and had written it as setMaxRows(1).findList().get(0), findUnique() seems like it would be more efficient. Not sure why they don't just offer a findFirst() though.

Answer (score 1):

For ebean 4.0.6 actually is:

this.find.query().setMaxRows(1).findUnique();